# Pairing Galaxy Note 2 to my car

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-2, bluetooth-pairing

I'm trying to pair my Note 2 to my car and the car keeps searching and fails even though the info for the car Bluetooth shows up on the phone. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you turned on Visibility of bluetooth? 
Go to settings> Bluetooth & turn on visibility by setting a visibility timeout(2 minutes or whatever is convenient for you)